# Getting the name of an input inside the last row

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the base of a table that I have.
It could have many more rows and the last number in the name attribute indicates the row number. I want get the name attribute of any of the inputs inside the last row. It does not matter which input is because then I will split the string and only keep the last number.

How can I achieve this? 
Thanks!

```
<table id="tableNames">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contact1_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="contact2_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="contact3_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone1_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone2_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone3_1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In the above example which value are you looking for?

Comment: So use the last selector....

Comment: @Avitus the name attribute of any input in the last row

Comment: @epascarello I was trying something like this but it does not work $("#tableNames > tr:last input:last").attr("name");

Comment: because tr is not a direct child of table.

Comment: @Azim Yes, I could use that. Any name attribute in the last row would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector with `split()` and `pop()`

```js
console.log( $("#tableNames tbody tr:last input:last").attr("name").split("_").pop())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableNames">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contact1_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="contact2_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="contact3_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone1_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone2_1"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone3_1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert($("#tableNames").find("tr:last").find("input").attr("name"));
})
```

Or a shorter version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert($("#tableNames tr:last input").attr("name"));
})
```

Here is a fiddle of this getting the name of the input on the last row:
https://jsfiddle.net/L7k2w6Ls/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tableNames tr:last input').map(function(){return $(this).attr('name');}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will do exactly what you are asking.  In an attempt to be more generally helpful, I want to make sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

It sounds like you are effectively encoding some application data in the name of your input elements.  It may be worth asking if that is what you actually want to do.  Often times I have data related to an element, and the best place to put that for jQuery to find is in the elements data array.  Even if the server *actually* needs that same piece of information in the name, putting the data somewhere more easily accessible to javascript can help minimize bugs in the future and simplify your application.  So I might suggest a completely different solution like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableNames">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contact1" data-more="1"/>
                <input type="text" name="contact2" data-more="1"/>
                <input type="text" name="contact3" data-more="1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone1" data-more="1"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone2" data-more="1"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone3" data-more="1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$( function(){
    $("#tableNames tr:last input").each( function(){
        var input = $(this);
        console.log( input.attr( 'name' ) + ' has data ' + input.data( 'more' ) );
    });
} );
```